# Ubuntu 18.04 unable to run a partial upgrade

Tags: apt, 18.04, partial-upgrade

I was trying to run a partial upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. But I am getting the following error

```
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-107-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-107-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-105-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-105-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-176-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-175-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-175-generic
grep: /media/user_name/writable/etc/lsb-release: Input/output error
grep: /media/user_name/writable/etc/lsb-release: Input/output error
grep: /media/user_name/writable/etc/lsb-release: Input/output error
grep: /media/user_name/writable/etc/lsb-release: Input/output error
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

On my machine, I have `lsb_release` installed. But not sure if it is relevant or not.
Any suggestion to fix the error?

**Edit 1**
I run the `sudo apt-get update` before I got the partial upgrade prompt. The result is:

```
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease [17.1 kB]                 
Hit:4 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                         
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic InRelease                    
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Err:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:10 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/6.4/ubuntu /bionic InRelease             
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease               
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease             
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                       
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: If you're being prompted for a "partial upgrade" it's because something is wrong. Please edit your question and include the output of both `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` so we can see what's going on with your package management

Comment: It looks like you've maybe added incompatible sources and PPAs. You shouldn't add sources from another distro, like Debian. Also, some PPAs can break your system. See: [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629). Bad sources can mess up dependencies.  I also see deadsnakes PPA which suggests that you have tried to install a different version of python from what's available in your release. This is well known to break your system since many aspects of Ubuntu rely on python. If you need a different python version for a task, use an [environment](https://askubuntu.com/q/244641)

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for your suggestions, I removed deadsnakes PPA and solved the update failure issue by following the answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306111/why-yarn-key-update-failes-all-the-time-gpg-error-https-dl-yarnpkg-com-debia

Comment: @Organic Marble Thanks and Yes, plus I mentioned the same link in my previous comment